# Как создать массив строк?

Tags: c++, массивы, строки

Как в C++ создается массив строк?
В JS это делается вот так: var arr = ['one', 'two'];
В C++ нет типа данных String как я понял. Как решить вопрос?

Comment: в с++ можно самому создавать типы данных или пользоваться бибилиотечными. `::std::array<::std::string, 2> arr{"one", "two"};`

Comment: В С++ существует масса разных способов "создать массив строк" и выбор конкретного способа зависит о того , зачем вам нужен этот массив и что вы с ним потом собираетесь делать. Невозможно дать осмысленного ответа на такой огульный вопрос, не обладая более конкретной информацией.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну почему же? В С++ есть тип `string`, и массив строк вполне можно создать как

```
string arr[] = { "one", "two" };
```

Можно использовать строки в стиле С, тогда это будет немного иначе -

```
char arr[][20] =  { "one", "two" };
```

(размер выбран условно).

Но раз уж используем С++, то лучше использовать

```
vector<string>
```